# How to create a simple scope in polymer dom-repeat

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, scope, polymer, dom-repeat

I'm looking for a simply way to create a scope inside a `dom-repeat`. In the example below, I have a list of `userIds` (E.g.: `[12,34,45]`). I want to loop through each element and retrieve the user object from the firebase-database. Finally, I want to print the user name.

My problem: The inside of the template does not create a scope. Therefore, the `{{user}}` object will always be overwritten and prints will all show the same user name.

Current Solution: Create a new webcomponent (polymer element), that takes a `userId` as argument. The element itself will then use `<firebase-document>` and prints the user name.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[userIds]]">
    <firebase-document path="/users/[[userId]]" data="{{user}}"></firebase-document>
    User's name is [[user.name]]
</template>
```

Comment: Getting users from firebase database in a loop is not logical as `firebase-document` perform `async` database connection. Instead, you may retrieve user name in a `array.forEach` loop

Comment: Actually the `async` nature is exactly what I like. Let's says you have a friends list (Our users). And one user changes his/her name or picture. It will immediately update on the view. You don't have to refresh the page.

Comment: Below answer code which I use for the same purpose. And you may trigger with cloud function if any change, will reflect your friend list.

Answer (score 0):

You may retrieve username something like below code as connectin to database `async` task.

```
var users= [];
var db = firebase.database();
arr.forEach( (uid, inx )=>{                                                                                
    db.ref('users/'+ uid).once('value', snapshot=>{                                                                                                         
    if(snapshot.exists()) {                                                                                                                           
        users.push(snapshot.val().name);                                                                                                                              
    }
  if (inx == arr.length-1) { this.set('users', users) } // in order to list at dom-repeat                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
});
```

Comment: Generally I would prefer doing this in Polymer not JS. But your example uses `once()` instead of `on()`. The beauty of the Polymer-Firebase element is, that it live updates anything that changes in the DB.

Comment: With `on()` there will be too much listener. This may cause performance problems. But instead, I think to listen with Firebase cloud function will be better.

Comment: Really? I was always expecting that the firebase-sdk solved this problems. And since we use websockets, I could open as many `on()` as I want and won't feel any performance/bandwidth issues.

Comment: Thank you. However, nothing on this page indicated that I would have limit problems on the user's-side. I would always only deal with, let's say 100 friends in the friends list (= `100x on()`)

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the output of each iteration to the iterator variable (specified by the [`<dom-repeat>.as` property](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.DomRepeat#property-as), which is "item" by default), but the variable must be an object.

1. Wrap the elements (in `userIds`) into objects:

   ```
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_wrap(userIds)]]">...</template>

   // in Polymer element
   _wrap(userIds) {
     return userIds.map(userId => ({userId}));
   }
   ```
2. Reference that newly wrapped element in the template:

   ```
   <firebase-document path="/users/[[item.userId]]" ...>
   ```
3. Attach the output to the iterator variable, `item`, using curly brackets:

   ```
   <firebase-document data="{{item.user}}" ...>
   ```
4. Update your usage of the output to reference the iterator variable:

   ```
   <div>User's name is [[item.user.name]]</div>
   ```

The final code should be similar to this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_wrap(userIds)]]">
  <firebase-document path="/users/[[item.userId]]" data="{{item.user}}"></firebase-document>
  <div>User's name is [[item.user.name]]</div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/GyLamX?editors=1010)